# Django Rest Framework v3.0 : How to map custom serializer fields to model field while saving an object?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, serialization

My Class based view looks like this. "Get" is used for listing all bookings and "Post" is used for creating a new booking.

```
class BookingList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        bookings = Booking.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(bookings, 10)
        page = paginator.page(1)
        serializer = BookingSerializer(page.object_list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = BookingSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And my Serializer class looks like this.

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_alternate_var1')
    field2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_alternate_var2')

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('field1', 'field2','var3','var4')

    def get_alternate_field1(self, obj):
        return obj.var1

    def get_alternate_field2(self,obj):
        return obj.var2 

class Booking(models.Model):
    var1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    var2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    var3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    var4 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ....
```

Now, this works perfectly fine with GET method. How do I create a new object using POST? 
My post params are field1, field2, var3 and I've to add default value (uuid) to var4 before saving. I'm not able to map field1, field2 to Model's var1 and var2. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Calls the serializer.save() should create a new instance. From the docs

> Calling .save() will either create a new instance, or update an
>   existing instance, depending on if an existing instance was passed
>   when instantiating the serializer class:

I would change your param names on the post to match those of your models. Or manually in the post change the data dict so that those variables are there before handing them to your serializer.